# isort black strange behavior

Tags: python, isort

When applying isort 5.12.0 in pre-commit within a python file, it re-orders the imports in bad. In bitbucket pipelines, the same code orders correctly.

This correct code:

```
from dagster import build_init_resource_context
from module1 import setting
from module1.resources.apple import AppleConnector as apple_connector
from module1.resources.apple import apple_resource
from module1.samples.apple import (
    apple_schema as apple_schemas,
)
from jsonschema import validate
```

Gets re-ordered this way:

```
from dagster import build_init_resource_context
from module1.resources.apple import AppleConnector as apple_connector
from module1.resources.apple import apple_resource
from module1.samples.apple import (
    apple_schema as apple_schemas,
)
from jsonschema import validate

from module1 import setting
```

¿Why is it happening?

Comment: What exactly is `module1`? `isort` seems to be confused over what section it belongs to (for example, it might be treating `module1....` as a third-party module, but `module1` itself as a first-party module or a module in the local folder). There are configuration options that let you specify which section a given module should be considered to belong to.

Comment: Hi! module1 is a package developed by me. This is not external code, is code within the same project.

Comment: What's your isort config (command line args, `pyproject.toml`)? The second version appears correct. The first seems to be falsely detecting `module1` as a third-party package. You can fix that my marking `module1` as a first-party package in your isort config.

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned, in isort config had to add module1 as a first-party package and then pre-commit worked consistently in all the pipelines. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `.pre-commit-config.yaml` isort configuration, I had to add `module1` as a first-party package. That avoided different interpretations in different repositories. Then pre-commit worked consistently in all the pipelines.

```
-   repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/isort
    rev: 5.12.0
    hooks:
    -   id: isort
        args: ["--profile", "black", "--filter-files", "--project", "module1"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you specify `black` as a profile in the `isort` configuration to avoid any conflicts.

```
[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
```

Or if you're using `pre-commit`:

```
- repo: https://github.com/pycqa/isort
    rev: 5.6.4
    hooks:
      - id: isort
        args: ["--profile", "black", "--filter-files"]
```

Also, check out this article: https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/black_compatibility.html

Answer (score 0):

Personally the only thing that worked for me in the end was to create a `.isort.cfg` and set the profile there, and then specify the path to my settings file in `.pre-commit-config.yaml`.

`.isort.cfg`

```bash
[settings]
profile=black
```

`.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```yaml
- repo: https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort
    rev: 5.13.2
    hooks:
      - id: isort
        args: ['--settings-path', 'api/.isort.cfg']
```